# How to pass value from ng-click (AngularJS) to Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

How to get value from ng-click and **send to laravel for query**?

//.html

```
<div ng-controller="recipientsController">
        <div ng-repeat="recipient in recipients | orderBy:'-created_at'" ng-click="select(recipient.id)">
            <p class="recipientname">{{ recipient.name }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//xxController.js

```
$scope.select = function() {
    Comment.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.comments = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });

}
```

//xxService.js

```
get:function(){
        var comments = $http.get('api/comments');
        return comments;
    },
```

//xxController.php [laravel]

```
public function index()
{   
    $comments = DB::table('c')
        ->join('u', 'c.id', '=', 'u.id')
        ->select('u.id', 'u.name', 'c.comments', 'c.created_at')
        ->where('u.id','=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->orWhere('u.id','=', **39 => this part has to be from ng-click value**)
        ->orderBy('c.created_at','asc')
        ->get();
    return Response::json($comments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have passing the `recipient.id` parameter in your ng-click function but you did't retrieve the parameter in your js function

you need to retrieve the parameter

```
$scope.select = function(**id**) {
   var selectedId=id;//you can check here
    Comment.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.comments = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });

}
```

Comment: then how to pass selectedId to laravel?

Comment: via the function parameter .

Answer (score 0):

For passing data with `$http.get` method, there is second argument for `[config]` you can use that.

**see:** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get for more reference about get method